# Error: Coefficients: (4 not defined because of singularities) in R

Tags: r, dataframe, lm

I have some error in my code, which I couldn't figure out.
I have a dataframe "a", with:

```
row.names      GM      variance     stddev      skewness   correltomarket  DEratio
1   MMM     0.9785122   0.9998918   0.9999459   -1.049053   2.932738    0.07252799
```

Now, I need to find a linear model for the above dataframe with the following code

```
riskmodel <- lm(formula=((a$GM)~(a$variance)+(a$skewness)+
                         (a$correltomarket)+(a$DEratio)),data=a)
```

When I run this code, I get the following summary for the "riskmodel"

```
Call:
lm(formula = ((a$GM) ~ (a$variance) + (a$skewness) + (a$correlationtomarket) + 
    (a$DEratio)), data = a)

Residuals:
ALL 1 residuals are 0: no residual degrees of freedom!

Coefficients: (4 not defined because of singularities)
                      Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)             0.9785         NA      NA       NA
a$variance                  NA         NA      NA       NA
a$skewness                  NA         NA      NA       NA
a$correlationtomarket       NA         NA      NA       NA
a$DEratio                   NA         NA      NA       NA

Residual standard error: NaN on 0 degrees of freedom
```

I don't understand why and I would be really grateful to anyone who helps me with this. I have no idea whats going wrong.

Comment: In `lm`, you don't need to use `a$`, as you provide the data with `data=`.

Comment: Thank You :), I shall keep it mind. :)

Comment: @Pascal, Any idea why the NAs?

Comment: Please see Dason's answer. You cannot run a multiple linear regression with only one observation.

Comment: @Pascal, I have seen the answer but I don't quite understand it. can you explain me please? Thanks!

Comment: Mainly, there is nothing more to understand. As @Dason clairly said, "You can't find a model with 5 parameters with only a single observation." At this stage, you need statistical advices, and SO is not the right place for this.

Comment: I just figured it out! Thanks a lot! I needed to use more rows. Took sometime to understand that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have a single observation in your data.frame.  You can't fit a model with 5 parameters with only a single observation.  You would need at least six observations to be able to fit parameters and have an estimate of the variance.

Comment: I'm sorry, i dont quite get it, can you explain please? or a link that can help me here? Thanks!